# Should this community wiki question be re-opened?

Tags: discussion

During review, I stumbled across [Video editing software options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options) in the reopen queue. While it is technically too broad by current standards, it's also a Community wiki that's been revised 8 times over it's lefespan. It also has over 100K views, 95 upvotes on the question and 119 upvotes on the answers and is likely to be driving people to the site. The answers appear to be still relevant today. There's also been a couple of delete votes cast which IMHO flies in the face of [Please do not delete closed questions with many views and many upvotes](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9132/please-do-not-delete-closed-questions-with-many-views-and-many-upvotes) In my opinion, we should keep it and protect it so I VTR and protected it to avoid spam answers from new users. What does the community think about this?

Comment: We have a recent meta question [Does it make sense to kill this question?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17802) which is also about that video editing question. You may want to post an answer there. Also, should we close this as a duplicate of that? (Normally I'd just VTC here, but I don't want to act hastily, as my gold [meta-tag:discussion] badge lets me dupe questions by myself. I don't know if you saw that  question... but even if not, I still suggest against deleting this. This seems like a prime case where a dupe with different title and wording may help people find the primary question.)

Comment: @EliahKagan No, I hadn't seen that one. I concur that it shouldn't be deleted. I also think it would be more appropriate to reopen it and protect it. The historical significance banner idea is a good one so as not to encourage more big list questions I suppose.

Comment: I'll go ahead and close this meta question as a duplicate of [that question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17802) then. I don't think this meta question has to be separately open (and it doesn't seem like you feel it should be either), but if it turns out that it looks like it should be, feel free to ping me in a comment (and of course to vote to reopen it).

Comment: The 2 questions are closely related. I'm not sure they are duplicates though. I consider kill to be synonymous with delete. And reopening is an entirely different issue (although you brought it up in your answer). I'll leave it to you to decide.